# Create an array of first element of each array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in maxtrix form like this

```
var costs = [
        [4, 6, 8, 8],
        [6, 8, 6, 7],
        [5, 7, 6, 8],
    ];
```

how do i transform it to this

```
 [[4,6,5], [6,8,7], [8,6,5], [8,7,5]]
```

This is what am trying

```
var cols = [];

for(var i = 0; i<costs.length; i++)
{
    cols.push(costs[i][0]);
}

return col;
```

And this gives me `[4,6,5]`. I know am missing something, any help will be great. Thanks

Comment: Is costs guaranteed to only contain 3 arrays or can it be any number?

Comment: @Magrangs it can be any number

Comment: It's not that hard -> **http://jsfiddle.net/d1mbf71v/**

Comment: @adeneo Worth noting that the map function will only work in IE9 or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another `for` loop inside the first one:

```js
var costs = [
    [4, 6, 8, 8],
    [6, 8, 6, 7],
    [5, 7, 6, 8],
];

alert("Original: " + JSON.stringify(costs));

// Prepare array...
var cols = new Array(costs[0].length);
for(var i = 0; i < costs[0].length; i++) {
    cols[i] = new Array(costs.length);
}

// Assign values...
for(var i = 0; i < costs.length; i++) {
    for(var k = 0; k < costs[i].length; k++) {
        cols[k][i] = costs[i][k];
    }
}

alert("New: " + JSON.stringify(cols));
```

Comment: this outputs only three arrays instead of four